# PhantomJS throws error (rasterize.js)

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am trying phantomjs in MEAN stack for report generation but after installing phantom binaries in my ubuntu os server and using phantom node_module + rasterize.js throws below error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'events'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:1
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/dnode-protocol/index.js:126
Error: Cannot find module 'stream'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/lib/dnode.js:2
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/lib/dnode.js:154
Error: Cannot find module 'net'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/index.js:3
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/node_modules/dnode/index.js:138
Error: Cannot find module 'http'

phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:8
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:193
/home/kb/code/backend/backend/api_server/node_modules/phantom/phantom.js:194
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'phantom.createWebPage()')

:/modules/webpage.js:905
report.js:7
```

This is my test code.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open("http://www.google.com", function (status) {
      console.log("opened google? ", status);
      page.evaluate(function () { return document.title; }, function (result) {
        console.log('Page title is ' + result);
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: do you run `npm install` with stream, net, http module?

Comment: I already use http module in server.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try run command:
`npm install -g events stream net http`

However, I think that you did wrong way to setup a Node Project. For example, If you want to create a project requires PhantomJS. You should do the steps below:

```
# create project directory
mkdir myproject
cd myproject

# install phantomjs for your project
npm install --save phantomjs

# create your project file
```

Comment: eventually ~ this is what solved the issue.

npm install phantom --save

using from terminal,

node [filename]

It looks that phantomjs binaries has no access to the node and its modules to run the files.